# return an Array with swift2 from parse server

Tags: function, parse-platform, swift2

I have this code to my project for getting dummy data from my disk :

```
static func createEvents() -> [Event]
{
    [
        Event(featuredImge: UIIMage(name: "r1")),
        Event(featuredImge: UIIMage(name: "r2")),
        Event(featuredImge: UIIMage(name: "r3"))
    ]
```

but now I want to get the UIIMages from my parse server and here is my Parse code :

```
var myEventQuery = PFQuery(className:"event")

    myEventQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        } else if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {


                //MARK: I choose the poster field in our Event class and download it as an Image
                let imageFile = object["poster"] as! PFFile

                let eventTitle = object["name"]

                imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error != nil {

                        print(error)

                    } else {

                        if let data = imageData {

                            print("Success")

                            Event(featuredImage: UIImage(data: data)!)

                        }

                    }

                })

            }

        }

    }
```

How I can add my parse code inside the func createEvents() -> [Event] in order to return me the Event array ?

Thank you in advance,
KS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are parsing one imageData in success block, so if you want Events collectively to show somewhere else, you need to keep appending Event(featuredImage: UIImage(data: data)!) in class property arrayEvents(lets say) and reload data on each append since its updating.

Comment: Hello Nitesh and thank you so much for your quick response.

I'm a newbie in programming so if you can be more specific because I didn't understand what you mean.

If I understand right I have to save all the images from my parse server to an Event array and then return this Array ?

Thank you in advance,
KS

Comment: I have questions :
- at a time on one query you will be getting one image in getDataInBackgroundWithBlock right ?
- are there multiple queries you are calling for multiple images ?

Comment: Hello Nitesh, the query that I use return me all the objects that I have in the event class in the poster row.
Thank you for your time, KS

Comment: ok then as I suggested above, you got it right  you have to save all the images from your parse server to an Event array, but you don't need createEvents method since its asynchronously fetching image data so you have to maintain these values in one class property.